# how to sync third party app data backup automatically via iTunes

Tags: iphone, ios, backup, itunes

I worked on app in which user can add images and make notes about those images, which i stored in sqlite and i store cards in document directory. I have enabled file Sharing option in app so user can keep backup of app's data manually in her PC via iTunes.

Please consider this scenario: the user connects the device from time to time to iTunes, and the synch process takes place. however, she does NOT go into the File Sharing option which is one way to backup manually the data in PC. now, she drops the phone in the bathtub and it does not work or due to some other reason she lost her device.
 my question: when she gets a new phone, can she recover her data?

if yes, then how could we do this?
if no, then what is the correct way now to backup the third party app data.